# Como rellenar multiples inputs con diferentes datos de un mismo select

Tags: javascript, mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Quiero hacer lo siguiente, quiero llenar dos `input` desde un `select` hasta ahora he logrado solo pasar el valor de uno, el salario o el id a través del `value` quiero pasar los dos ya que necesito el `id`  del `option` selecionado para guardar en la base de datos

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <div class="float-lg-left col-sm-6">
                        <label style=" font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;  font-weight: bold;  font-size: 15px; color:black">POSICIÓN</label>
                        <select class="form-control form-control-line" onchange="getValue()" id="Position" name="Position" style=" font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;  font-weight: bold;  font-size: 14px; color:black">
                            @foreach (var position in Model.Positions)
                            {
                                <option value="@position.PositionID"  id="PositionID" name="PositionID">@position.Name</option>
                            }
                        </select>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="PositionID" id="PositionID" >

                    </div>
                    <div class="float-lg-right col-sm-6">
                        <label style=" font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;  font-weight: bold;  font-size: 15px; color:black">SALARIO</label>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="Salary" id="Salary" style=" font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;  font-weight: bold;  font-size: 15px; color:black" readonly>

                    </div>
```

Este el es script solo puedo cargar un solo dato quiero pasar dos el `id` y el `salario`

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "/Employees/GetData",
          data: "{}",
          success: function (data) {
              var s = '<option value="">SELECCIONE POSICIÓN</option>';
              for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                  s += '<option id="' + data[i].PositionID + '" value="' +  data[i].PositionID +'">' + data[i].Name + '</option>';
              }

              $("#Position").html(s);
              $("#PositionID").html(s);
          }
      });
  });

  function getValue() {
      var myVal = $("#Position").val();
      $("#Salary").val(myVal);

      var ID = $("#PositionID").val();
      $("#PositionID").val(ID);
  }
```

Controlador

```
public ActionResult GetData()
    {
        var data = from post in db.PositionsEmployees select new { post.Name, post.Salary, post.PositionID };
        return Json(data.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: `$("#PositionID").html(s);` Con esto estas intentado rellenar un `input` con el `html` de varios options... ¿Que es exactamente lo que quieres hacer? ¿Rellenar un input con **varios** valores `value="1-6-8"`?¿O que al seleccionar una opcion de ese select se rellenen los inputs con los valores de ese option?

Comment: Que al seleccionar una opción de ese select se llenen los inputs con los valores de ese option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el `JSON` que retornas están los 2 valores... por lo que voy a suponer que tu problema es asignarle estos valores al `option` pero como solo tienes un atributo `value` no sabes como hacerlo.

**Atributos data (HTML5):**

> Los atributos data-*  nos permiten almacenar información adicional
>   sobre elementos HTML semánticos estándar sin otros hacks como
>   atributos no estándar, propiedades adicionales en el DOM, o
>   Node.setUserData(). [mas info](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/HTML/como/Usando_atributos_de_datos)

Conociendo esto podríamos usar un atributo `data` como por ejemplo `data-salary`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Employees/GetData",
        data: "{}",
        success: function (data) {
            var s = '<option value="">SELECCIONE POSICIÓN</option>';
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                s += '<option id="' + data[i].PositionID + '" value="' +  data[i].PositionID +'" data-salary="'+data[i].Salary+'">' + data[i].Name + '</option>';
            }

            $("#Position").html(s);
        }
    });
});
```

Como te he puesto en los comentarios, he borrado la parte `$("#PositionID").html(s);` ya que estas intentado ponerle a un `input` el html de toda una estructura de select con options.

Y por último en la función `getValue()`:

```
function getValue() {
    //Salary:
    $("#Salary").val($("#Position option:selected").data("salary"));

    //ID:
    $("#PositionID").val($("#Position").val());
}
```

**Snippet:**

```js
function getValue(){
  $("#PositionID").val($("#Position").val());
  //Por el option con el ID del select
  //$("#Salary").val($("#Position option[value='"+$("#Position").val()+"']").data("salary"));
  //Por el option selected y con attr
  //$("#Salary").val($("#Position option:selected").attr("data-salary"));
  //Option selected y .data de jQuery la opción mas correcta:
  $("#Salary").val($("#Position option:selected").data("salary"));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="Position" name="Position" onchange="getValue()">
    <option value="1" data-salary="200">1</option>
    <option value="2" data-salary="400">2</option>
    <option value="3" data-salary="600">3</option>
    <option value="4" data-salary="800">4</option>
    <option value="5" data-salary="1000">5</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="PositionID" name="PositionID">
<input type="number" id="Salary" name="Salary" readonly>
```

---

Como observación he visto que escribes el nombre de los `id` y `names` con **UpperCamelCase**, esto no es una practica muy común lo mas habitual es usar **lowerCamelCase**

Comment: Gracias amigo se lo agradezco bastante, si pudieras ver mi otra pregunta sobre un error 500 al cargar una vista parcial y ayudarme me harías un favor inmenso ya que por estas dos cositas he estado atrasado en un proyecto final y me urge terminarlo